# How to find my hp server is 9000 or Integrity?

Tags: hp-ux

My server is HP Unix B.11.31 and I want to check whether it is 9000 type or Integrity type.

Comment: have you tried `machinfo`  or more concisely `model` ?

Comment: @Archemar `model` shows the type...  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model can be found using

```
model

ia64 hp Superdome2 16s

XYZ/9000/rx3440 (a)
```

more details information can be found usinf `machinfo` (starting 11iV3).

other properties are foung using getconf (see `man getconf` for details)

```
getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

- <s>here I am on a 32 bit system.</s>
- as pointed out by Darkheart, actual configuration is given by `getconf KERNEL_BITS` which return 64.

( (a) can't remember exact return for 9000 system )

Comment: Are you sure that you are on a 32bit system? `getconf -v XBS5_LP64_OFF64  LONG_BIT`  - that just tells you how many bits a 'long' type is for that specification ( `defaults to XBS5_ILP32_OFF32` ) ... I think you want KERNEL_BITS or 'HW_CPU_SUPP_BITS'